# WSO2 Identity Server startup error - Error in initializing thrift transport

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I just installed WSO IS and receive this error when starting the server.

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent} 
-  Failed to initialize Entitlement Service

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent} 
-  Error in initializing thrift transport
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not bind to port 10500

I've verified nothing is using the 10500 port.

Comment: Is there anymore exception get throwed? If so can you please share the full exception.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but you can try this:

1.Kill the java process if windows system or in Linux check if another process running 
already which was not shut down properly by searching using ps -ef | grep java.

2.Restart the IS server.

Answer (score 2):

In order to test WSO2 locally on my development workstation, I hard-coded a hostname via the hosts file and modified the HostName and MgtHostName entities in ./repository/conf/carbon.xml. One caveat is that my workstation has a dynamic IP address. When the IP does occasionally change, leaving the hostname pointing to an unresponsive IP, starting WSO2 IS fails with the exact same error.

Repairing the host entry and restarting the WSO2 Identity Server resolves it.